# Trouble getting Information from API in python. Check description

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I'm trying to get information from this API:
https://sweltering-back-5405.nanoscaleapi.io/secretpi

But I'm getting a response 200

I'm using python 3.5

This is the code:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://sweltering-back-5405.nanoscaleapi.io/secretpi')
print(resp)
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 200 means success. What's the problem? I'd guess that you need to inspect the response for the information you requested. Start by reading the documentation. Quite why so many people omit this step escapes me.

Comment: because thats what it is expected from a working api please read upon htttp status codes and how `python requests` works

Answer (score 0):

200 is the status code returned if the request you made is successful. You will have to read the response body or whatever it is you want from the response you received.

For example

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://sweltering-back-5405.nanoscaleapi.io/secretpi')
print(resp.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I get an additional 'b' in front of the output. Why is that?